# How to confirm if undervolt is working in Ubuntu?

Tags: intel-cpu

I have managed to under-volt my Intel 8750H by 150 mV using https://github.com/kitsunyan/intel-undervolt. But I am not sure if the settings are really applied.

Answer (score 1):

The readme provided explains it:

> Run `intel-undervolt read` to read current values and `intel-undervolt apply` to apply configured values.

The output will show applied settings. Run `intel-undervolt read` first to check, then `intel-undervolt apply`, followed by another `intel-undervolt read` to verify that new settings is in fact applied.

Comment: Yes, but I was looking to confirm it by some other means.

Comment: Actually, It is not working on alienware M15R4  `Debian 11, i9-10980HK CPU`.